# how do I change this code to return multiple different items

Tags: c#, oop, factory-pattern

this example of a factory; http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory
returns 1 thing. How would I change it to return something like this;

```
string device = "";
string deviceTypeID = "";
int deviceTypeCode = 0;
bool true
```

as an example, in each concrete class, I would make look like this;

```
string device = "bracelet";
string deviceTypeID = "male";
int deviceTypeCode = 0;
bool true
```

or, for another concrete class;

```
string device = "ring";
string deviceTypeID = "female";
int deviceTypeCode = 8;
bool false
```

I think I would need to make an object inside each concrete class, but since I am quite new to C#, this is stretching my understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want some default `Empty` property which is implemented commonly in some .NET classes/structures like `Point`, `Rectangle`...?

Answer (score 2):

Group them together in a `class`

```
sealed class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass(string device, string deviceTypeId, int deviceTypeCode, bool someBool)
    {
        this.Device = device;
        this.DeviceTypeId = deviceTypeId;
        this.DeviceTypeCode = deviceTypeCode;
        this.SomeBool = someBool
    }

    string Device { get; private set; }
    string DeviceTypeId { get; private set; }
    int DeviceTypeCode { get; private set; }
    bool SomeBool { get; private set; }
}
```

Then return it in your `factory`.

```
return new MyClass("bracelet", "male", 0, false);
```

Implementation of your class may vary, I've implemented it here so that you may only read from it (can't change it after it is made).

Comment: Adam, I think I understand what you have done there, but I am having trouble implementing it. Could you show how this fits into the Factory example? I'm coming from LabVIEW and I'm having to unlearn some really bad habits and assumptions.

Comment: A `factory` just returns an `object` (an instance of a `class`) when you call some method it has (usually named something obvious like `Make()`). Lets say your `factory` only returns a `String`. You'd write something like `return "Hello"` in the last line of the `Make()` method of your factory. Another way of writing that might be `return new String("Hello")` both would *work*. Here you want to return a `MyClass` so you'd write `return new MyClass(a, b, c...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a new class (or struct if you're going to be creating lots of these):

```
public class Container
{
  public string Device;
  public string DeviceTypeID;
  public int DeviceTypeCode;
  public bool MyBool;
}
```

Then have your factory create this class and return it:

`return new Container { Device = "bracelet", DeviceTypeID = "male" };`

Comment: I can't certainly understand this `or struct if you're going to be creating lots of these` ?

Comment: structs have less overhead to create than classes. So if you are creating many classes, your application will be faster and use less memory if you use a struct instead.

Comment: I hope you know when we pass struct it is copied and passed. So if you pass it to any method you're basically creating new instance, then copying the values and passing it. That creates more overhead IMO. on the other hand I agree with you when we don't need to pass it to any method or property etc.

Comment: I believe the guidelines are that a `struct` isn't worth it unless they're *small* and/or you understand all the pitfalls they incur. I wouldn't recommend a blanket "they're higher performance". This is only true if you're creating quite low-level constructs (most C# .NET dev's wont need to).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add something on to Adam Kewley's great answer. If your factory is going to create and return many items, it may be useful to set up a static dictionary and refer to them by their keys. In a real world situation, you'd probably have your "devices" stored in a database and cached by your program, but this might be a useful way for you to explore details of implementing a factory pattern.

```
    class ItemFactory
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, MyClass> knownItems = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>
        {
            {"bracelet", new MyClass("bracelet", "male", 0, true)},
            {"ring", new MyClass("ring","female",8,false)}
        };

        public MyClass createItemByType(string itemType)
        {
            if (knownItems.ContainsKey(itemType))
                return (knownItems[itemType]); 
            // default behavior if an item isn't found.
            // maybe throw an exception here, depending on your needs. 
            return new MyClass(); // unknown item
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is more realistic. However, if the author isn't used to reference passing they might run into issues of shared mutability. The same `MyClass` is retrieved for every 'bracelet' query. Any edits will then be shared application wide.

Also, using string based factories in the source code introduces an element of baking in information. I'd argue that stateful information (such as the gender of an item) should either be handled using IO (e.g. a database or config file) or a centralized set of `const` keys; otherwise, refactoring will become increasingly difficult as the application grows

Comment: Yeah, consts or enums -- both for gender and ID if not the database